# Convert clock time to minutes

Tags: asp.net-3.5

How to convert the time 11:21:21 into total minutes?

Comment: You really need help multiplying something by 60...?

Answer (score 2):

Get the time as a TimeSpan value using the TimeOfDay method, then use the TotalMinutes method to get the time in minutes:

```
DateTime t = new DateTime(0, 0, 0, 11, 21, 21);
double minutes = t.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes;
```

The minutes variable now contains `681.35`. If you want the value as whole minutes use Math.Round or Math.Floor, depending on how you want it rounded:

```
int minutes = (int)Math.Floor(t.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
totalMins = (60 * hrs) + mins + (secs / 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this. Thanks for astander.

I have video time sometime like this "01:22:03" sometime like this "55:43"

And I convert this time to minudes like this

```
public string converttomins(String val2)
{
    int hrs, mins, secs;
    int totalMins;
    if (val2.Length > 6)
    {
        hrs = Convert.ToInt32(val2.Substring(0, 2));
        mins = Convert.ToInt32(val2.Substring(3, 2));
        secs = Convert.ToInt32(val2.Substring(6, 2));
        totalMins = (60 * hrs) + mins + (secs / 60);
    }
    else
    {
        //hrs = Convert.ToInt32(val2.Substring(0, 2));
        mins = Convert.ToInt32(val2.Substring(0, 2));
        secs = Convert.ToInt32(val2.Substring(3, 2));
        totalMins = mins + (secs / 60);
    }

    //Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Convert.ToString(totalMins) + "')</script>");
    return Convert.ToString(totalMins) + " dakika";
}
```

and I send my time like this

```
<%# converttomins(Convert.ToString(Eval("sure"))) %>
```

It's worked perfectly for me.